# How can I use reflection in order to return an "added" enum value from a method?

Tags: java, enums

I am in reference to the following article about **reflection** and **enums**:

https://www.niceideas.ch/roller2/badtrash/entry/java_create_enum_instances_dynamically

And the corresponding source code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessor;
import sun.reflect.FieldAccessor;
import sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory;

public class ReflectionUtils {

    private static ReflectionFactory reflectionFactory = ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory();

    private static void setFailsafeFieldValue(Field field, Object target, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException {

        // let's make the field accessible
        field.setAccessible(true);

        // next we change the modifier in the Field instance to
        // not be final anymore, thus tricking reflection into
        // letting us modify the static final field
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        int modifiers = modifiersField.getInt(field);

        // blank out the final bit in the modifiers int
        modifiers &= ~Modifier.FINAL;
        modifiersField.setInt(field, modifiers);

        FieldAccessor fa = reflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(field, false);
        fa.set(target, value);
    }

    private static void blankField(Class<?> enumClass, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        for (Field field : Class.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getName().contains(fieldName)) {
                AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[]{field}, true);
                setFailsafeFieldValue(field, enumClass, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void cleanEnumCache(Class<?> enumClass) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        blankField(enumClass, "enumConstantDirectory"); // Sun (Oracle?!?) JDK 1.5/6
        blankField(enumClass, "enumConstants"); // IBM JDK
    }

    private static ConstructorAccessor getConstructorAccessor(Class<?> enumClass, Class<?>[] additionalParameterTypes)
            throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[additionalParameterTypes.length + 2];
        parameterTypes[0] = String.class;
        parameterTypes[1] = int.class;
        System.arraycopy(additionalParameterTypes, 0, parameterTypes, 2, additionalParameterTypes.length);
        return reflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(enumClass.getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes));
    }

    private static Object makeEnum(Class<?> enumClass, String value, int ordinal, Class<?>[] additionalTypes,
                                   Object[] additionalValues) throws Exception {
        Object[] parms = new Object[additionalValues.length + 2];
        parms[0] = value;
        parms[1] = Integer.valueOf(ordinal);
        System.arraycopy(additionalValues, 0, parms, 2, additionalValues.length);
        return enumClass.cast(getConstructorAccessor(enumClass, additionalTypes).newInstance(parms));
    }

    /**
     * Add an enum instance to the enum class given as argument
     *
     * @param <T>      the type of the enum (implicit)
     * @param enumType the class of the enum to be modified
     * @param enumName the name of the new enum instance to be added to the class.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Enum<?>> void addEnum(Class<T> enumType, String enumName) {

        // 0. Sanity checks
        if (!Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(enumType)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("class " + enumType + " is not an instance of Enum");
        }

        // 1. Lookup "$VALUES" holder in enum class and get previous enum instances
        Field valuesField = null;
        Field[] fields = TestEnum.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getName().contains("$VALUES")) {
                valuesField = field;
                break;
            }
        }
        AccessibleObject.setAccessible(new Field[]{valuesField}, true);

        try {

            // 2. Copy it
            T[] previousValues = (T[]) valuesField.get(enumType);
            List<T> values = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(previousValues));

            // 3. build new enum
            T newValue = (T) makeEnum(enumType, // The target enum class
                    enumName, // THE NEW ENUM INSTANCE TO BE DYNAMICALLY ADDED
                    values.size(),
                    new Class<?>[]{}, // could be used to pass values to the enum constuctor if needed
                    new Object[]{}); // could be used to pass values to the enum constuctor if needed

            // 4. add new value
            values.add(newValue);

            // 5. Set new values field
            setFailsafeFieldValue(valuesField, null, values.toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(enumType, 0)));

            // 6. Clean enum cache
            cleanEnumCache(enumType);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private static enum TestEnum {
        a,
        b,
        c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Dynamically add 3 new enum instances d, e, f to TestEnum
        addEnum(TestEnum.class, "d");
        addEnum(TestEnum.class, "e");
        addEnum(TestEnum.class, "f");

        // Run a few tests just to show it works OK.
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(TestEnum.values()));
        // Shows : [a, b, c, d, e, f]
    }
}
```

I somehow need to return one of the new enum values from a method:

```
public TestEnum theValue() {
    return TestEnum.f;
}
```

Of course, this won't compile. How can I return say `f` (which is one of the added enum values) from the above method?

**edit**:

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
private TestEnum testEnum;

@Override
public TestEnum theValue() {
    ReflectionUtils.addEnum(TestEnum.class, "f");
    //How can I set the testEnum field to have 'f' as a value?
    return this.testEnum;
}
```

Comment: That code is really horrible. It relies on knowledge of particular implementations of Java and can break if you try it on a different implementation (Android, for example, is neither Oracle nor IBM...). Anyway, whatever you create with reflection, you have to use with reflection. Which strongly suggests you should consider *not* using enums for this.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic. I do appreciate the risk of using **sun** packages... I am considering introducing this to the test package only.

Comment: I have edited my post. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your method from

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> void addEnum(Class<T> enumType, String enumName)
```

to

```
public static <T extends Enum<?>> T addEnum(Class<T> enumType, String enumName)
```

and return the value from this method.

```
// 6. Clean enum cache
cleanEnumCache(enumType);

// 7. Clean enum cache
return newvalue;
```

and return `newvalue` from the exception block.

However it does not seem a good idea to me to do such reflection - as most other commenters pointed out. If it is not because of non-modifiable third-party sources, you should redesign your problem to work without this kind of enums.

Comment: Basically my production code (src/main/java) relies on an enum for a return value and we want to introduce a new enum value in test (src/test/java) for testing purposes. The above reflection utils will never make it to production code though.

Comment: Using reflection enums for tests - seems quite reasonable to me.